# How to plot contourf for two dimensional with single value of solution

Tags: python, python-2.7, plot

Please help,

I'm trying to plot some math model in 2 dimensional input variables. I was trying to plot contour.

```
 x1 = np.linspace(1,10,1)
 x2 = np.linspace(1,10,1)
 x, y = np.meshgrid(x1,x2)
```

I have done this, but the solution of the mathematics operations are complicated. Because it involved matrix operations. And finally the final answer will occur in list form.

Any idea how to do the plot? Because when try to code

```
plt.figure()
cp = np.contourf(x,y,solution)
plt.colorbar(cp)
plt.show()
```

It gives me error and mention the z value must in 2D array

Answer (score 0):

You need to [reshape](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) your output data. If i am not mistaken, your "solution" is currently a 1D array, each element of the array corresponds to (x,y) tuple. To plot a contour you need to have 2D array with dimensions dim(solution) = (dim(x), dim(y)).

Though reshaping after the calculations is faster, you can also pre-define your solution as a 2D-array, and save its (i,j) elements after each iteration. The latter solution would be slower, depending on your dimensions and code.

Comment: How to do reshaping after the calculations?

Comment: check out the page http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html